# Export magento orders per product

Tags: orders, csv, export, magento1.9.3.1

I need to export magento orders per product ( I want to get all the orders for a specific product) How could I do it?

Comment: what is your magento version?

Comment: 1.9.31 this is the version

Comment: reference extension link : https://marketplace.magento.com/raveinfosys-raveinfosys-orderexporter.html

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure how to use it to filter order per product

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order collection which contains specific products in the order by following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
if($sku = $_product->getSku()){
    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('order_item' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id',array('sku'));
    $collection->getSelect()->where("order_item.sku like ?", "%$sku%")->group('main_table.entity_id');
}
```

After that you can export it according to your requirement. This is not for export but for filter the order collection by sku or product.

Hope this help!